# Get the time of the nearest run of build-in timer

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

As it's said at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx):

> Windows has a built-in timer that runs background tasks in 15-minute intervals.

Let's assume that we make use a [TimeTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) with some *freshness* time. The Task will be scheduled with the nearst build-in timer tick - depending on the time when we register our Task, the time left to scheduling can vary.

Is it possible to get the time when our Task will be scheduled?

Comment: Out of curiosity, may I ask why do you want to do that? I don't think it's possible, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @yasen For example I plan to set a *one-shot* TimeTrigger and it would be suitable to inform the User about the exact time. Without knowing the exact time *one-shot* Task seems to be a little *random* feature.

Answer (score 0):

One solution which comes to my mind is to make another simple BackgroundTask with TimeTrigger set to *one-shot* and minimum *freshnes stime*. The job of this Task would be to save in LocalSettings the `DateTime.Now` to a variable.

As the build-in timer runs in constant intervals then I will be able to count the time of the next nearest run.

The disavantage of this solution is that after the OS restart I will have to update the variable. So it means that just after starting my App I would have to run this additional task to ensure about the correct value.

It means that I will be able to set the TimeTrigger more accurately after the first tick of buil-in timer.